# Spring boot jpa method to Retrive all the departments for a repective locations or all the customers assigned to a user

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I know how it can be done using Query but I'm searching for methods in simples words I want to know how to create a method for Spring JPA for the Query which uses "where" condition...

I searched for documentation but didn't found any "where" type method for Spring jpa.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a repository that searches for a User with a certain username.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
     User findByName(String name);
}
```

As you can see above, the findByName gets translated to a `SELECT .... WHERE name = :name` query clause.

Comment: You are right here but What if I want all users names based on the selected regions and both the regions and users have separate tables but are joined using the keys?

Comment: The faster way is to use as you said the `@Query` annotation, otherwise you will need to do some complex jpa syntax naming,